# Selecting all components within a box

Tags: autodesk-forge

We would like to develop a click and drag box for the viewer that then selects all components within the box. Do you have any tips, code snippets for this?

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You should proceed with two passes:

1/ do a bounding box check on each component:

2/ from there 3 possibilities:

- a/ component bounding box is inside your box -> inside, done
- b/ component bounding box is outside your box -> outside, done
- c/ component bounding box intersects your box -> need a finer check,
  iterate the vertices of the component and check if each is inside or
  outside. Could be expensive depending on the shape of your geometry

Check my series on window selection, it's following this logic except that it's not a box but a pyramidal shape. A box would be easier.

[Custom Window Selection in the Forge Viewer - Part I](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-window-selection-forge-viewer-part-i)

[Custom Window Selection in the Forge Viewer - Part II](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-window-selection-forge-viewer-part-ii)

[Custom Window Selection in the Forge Viewer - Part III](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-window-selection-forge-viewer-part-iii)

The most relevant code is in [Viewing.Extension.SelectionWindow.SelectSet.js](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/blob/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.SelectionWindow/Viewing.Extension.SelectionWindow.SelectSet.js)

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// SelectSet util for Selection Window in Forge Viewer
// By Philippe Leefsma, September 2017
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
import geometryIntersectsBox3 from './GeometryIntersectsBox3'
import Toolkit from 'Viewer.Toolkit'

export default class SelectSet {

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  constructor (viewer) {

    this.viewer = viewer
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Set model: required to compute the bounding boxes
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  async setModel (model) {

    this.model = model

    const instanceTree = model.getData().instanceTree

    const rootId = instanceTree.getRootId()

    const bbox =
      await this.getComponentBoundingBox(
      model, rootId)

    this.boundingSphere = bbox.getBoundingSphere()

    const leafIds = await Toolkit.getLeafNodes (model)

    this.boundingBoxInfo = leafIds.map((dbId) => {

      const bbox = this.getLeafComponentBoundingBox(
        model, dbId)

      return {
        bbox,
        dbId
      }
    })
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Returns bounding box as it appears in the viewer
  // (transformations could be applied)
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  getModifiedWorldBoundingBox (fragIds, fragList) {

    const fragbBox = new THREE.Box3()
    const nodebBox = new THREE.Box3()

    fragIds.forEach(function(fragId) {

      fragList.getWorldBounds(fragId, fragbBox)

      nodebBox.union(fragbBox)
    })

    return nodebBox
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Returns bounding box for fragment list
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  async getComponentBoundingBox (model, dbId) {

    const fragIds = await Toolkit.getFragIds(
      model, dbId)

    const fragList = model.getFragmentList()

    return this.getModifiedWorldBoundingBox(
      fragIds, fragList)
  }

  getLeafComponentBoundingBox (model, dbId) {

    const fragIds = Toolkit.getLeafFragIds(
      model, dbId)

    const fragList = model.getFragmentList()

    return this.getModifiedWorldBoundingBox(
      fragIds, fragList)
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Creates Raycaster object from the mouse pointer
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  pointerToRay (pointer) {

    const camera = this.viewer.navigation.getCamera()
    const pointerVector = new THREE.Vector3()
    const rayCaster = new THREE.Raycaster()
    const pointerDir = new THREE.Vector3()
    const domElement = this.viewer.canvas

    const rect = domElement.getBoundingClientRect()

    const x =  ((pointer.clientX - rect.left) / rect.width) * 2 - 1
    const y = -((pointer.clientY - rect.top) / rect.height) * 2 + 1

    if (camera.isPerspective) {

      pointerVector.set(x, y, 0.5)

      pointerVector.unproject(camera)

      rayCaster.set(camera.position,
        pointerVector.sub(
          camera.position).normalize())

    } else {

      pointerVector.set(x, y, -15)

      pointerVector.unproject(camera)

      pointerDir.set(0, 0, -1)

      rayCaster.set(pointerVector,
        pointerDir.transformDirection(
          camera.matrixWorld))
    }

    return rayCaster.ray
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Returns true if the box is contained inside the
  // closed volume defined by the the input planes
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  containsBox (planes, box) {

    const {min, max} = box

    const vertices = [
      new THREE.Vector3(min.x, min.y, min.z),
      new THREE.Vector3(min.x, min.y, max.z),
      new THREE.Vector3(min.x, max.y, max.z),
      new THREE.Vector3(max.x, max.y, max.z),
      new THREE.Vector3(max.x, max.y, min.z),
      new THREE.Vector3(max.x, min.y, min.z),
      new THREE.Vector3(min.x, max.y, min.z),
      new THREE.Vector3(max.x, min.y, max.z)
    ]

    for (let vertex of vertices) {

      for (let plane of planes) {

        if (plane.distanceToPoint(vertex) < 0) {

          return false
        }
      }
    }

    return true
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Returns true if at least one vertex is contained in
  // closed volume defined by the the input planes
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  containsVertex (planes, vertices) {

    for (let vertex of vertices) {

      let isInside = true

      for (let plane of planes) {

        if (plane.distanceToPoint(vertex) < 0) {

          isInside = false
          break
        }
      }

      if (isInside) {

        return true
      }
    }

    return false
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Returns the oriented camera plane
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  getCameraPlane () {

    const camera = this.viewer.navigation.getCamera()

    const normal = camera.target.clone().sub(
      camera.position).normalize()

    const pos = camera.position

    const dist =
      - normal.x * pos.x
      - normal.y * pos.y
      - normal.z * pos.z

    return new THREE.Plane (normal, dist)
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Creates pyramid geometry to perform tri-box
  // intersection analysis
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  createPyramidGeometry (vertices) {

    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry()

    geometry.vertices = vertices

    geometry.faces = [
      new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2),
      new THREE.Face3(0, 2, 3),
      new THREE.Face3(1, 0, 4),
      new THREE.Face3(2, 1, 4),
      new THREE.Face3(3, 2, 4),
      new THREE.Face3(0, 3, 4)
    ]

    return geometry
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Determine if the bounding boxes are
  // inside, outside or intersect with the selection window
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  filterBoundingBoxes (planes, vertices, partialSelect) {

    const geometry = this.createPyramidGeometry(vertices)

    const intersect = []
    const outside = []
    const inside = []

    for (let bboxInfo of this.boundingBoxInfo) {

      // if bounding box inside, then we can be sure
      // the mesh is inside too

      if (this.containsBox (planes, bboxInfo.bbox)) {

        inside.push(bboxInfo)

      } else if (partialSelect) {

        // otherwise need a more precise tri-box
        // analysis to determine if the bbox intersect
        // the pyramid geometry

        const intersects = geometryIntersectsBox3(
          geometry, bboxInfo.bbox)

        intersects.length
          ? intersect.push(bboxInfo)
          : outside.push(bboxInfo)

      } else {

        outside.push(bboxInfo)
      }
    }

    return {
      intersect,
      outside,
      inside
    }
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Runs the main logic of the select set:
  // computes a pyramid shape from the selection window
  // corners and determines enclosed meshes from the model
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  compute (pointer1, pointer2, partialSelect) {

    // build 4 rays to project the 4 corners
    // of the selection window

    const xMin = Math.min(pointer1.clientX, pointer2.clientX)
    const xMax = Math.max(pointer1.clientX, pointer2.clientX)

    const yMin = Math.min(pointer1.clientY, pointer2.clientY)
    const yMax = Math.max(pointer1.clientY, pointer2.clientY)

    const ray1 = this.pointerToRay({
      clientX: xMin,
      clientY: yMin
    })

    const ray2 = this.pointerToRay({
      clientX: xMax,
      clientY: yMin
    })

    const ray3 = this.pointerToRay({
      clientX: xMax,
      clientY: yMax
    })

    const ray4 = this.pointerToRay({
      clientX: xMin,
      clientY: yMax
    })

    // first we compute the top of the pyramid
    const top = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0)

    top.add (ray1.origin)
    top.add (ray2.origin)
    top.add (ray3.origin)
    top.add (ray4.origin)

    top.multiplyScalar(0.25)

    // we use the bounding sphere to determine
    // the height of the pyramid
    const {center, radius} = this.boundingSphere

    // compute distance from pyramid top to center
    // of bounding sphere

    const dist = new THREE.Vector3(
      top.x - center.x,
      top.y - center.y,
      top.z - center.z)

    // compute height of the pyramid:
    // to make sure we go far enough,
    // we add the radius of the bounding sphere

    const height = radius + dist.length()

    // compute the length of the side edges

    const angle = ray1.direction.angleTo(
      ray2.direction)

    const length = height / Math.cos(angle * 0.5)

    // compute bottom vertices

    const v1 = new THREE.Vector3(
      ray1.origin.x + ray1.direction.x * length,
      ray1.origin.y + ray1.direction.y * length,
      ray1.origin.z + ray1.direction.z * length)

    const v2 = new THREE.Vector3(
      ray2.origin.x + ray2.direction.x * length,
      ray2.origin.y + ray2.direction.y * length,
      ray2.origin.z + ray2.direction.z * length)

    const v3 = new THREE.Vector3(
      ray3.origin.x + ray3.direction.x * length,
      ray3.origin.y + ray3.direction.y * length,
      ray3.origin.z + ray3.direction.z * length)

    const v4 = new THREE.Vector3(
      ray4.origin.x + ray4.direction.x * length,
      ray4.origin.y + ray4.direction.y * length,
      ray4.origin.z + ray4.direction.z * length)

    // create planes

    const plane1 = new THREE.Plane()
    const plane2 = new THREE.Plane()
    const plane3 = new THREE.Plane()
    const plane4 = new THREE.Plane()
    const plane5 = new THREE.Plane()

    plane1.setFromCoplanarPoints(top, v1, v2)
    plane2.setFromCoplanarPoints(top, v2, v3)
    plane3.setFromCoplanarPoints(top, v3, v4)
    plane4.setFromCoplanarPoints(top, v4, v1)
    plane5.setFromCoplanarPoints( v3, v2, v1)

    const planes = [
      plane1, plane2,
      plane3, plane4,
      plane5
    ]

    const vertices = [
      v1, v2, v3, v4, top
    ]

    // filter all bounding boxes to determine
    // if inside, outside or intersect

    const result = this.filterBoundingBoxes(
      planes, vertices, partialSelect)

    // all inside bboxes need to be part of the selection

    const dbIdsInside = result.inside.map((bboxInfo) => {

      return bboxInfo.dbId
    })

    // if partialSelect = true
    // we need to return the intersect bboxes

    if (partialSelect) {

      const dbIdsIntersect = result.intersect.map((bboxInfo) => {

        return bboxInfo.dbId
      })

      // At this point perform a finer analysis
      // to determine if the any of the mesh vertices are inside
      // or outside the selection window but it would
      // be a much more expensive computation

      //const dbIdsIntersectAccurate =
      //  dbIdsIntersect.filter((dbId) => {
      //
      //    const geometry =
      //      Toolkit.buildComponentGeometry(
      //        this.viewer, this.viewer.model, dbId)
      //
      //    return this.containsVertex(
      //      planes, geometry.vertices)
      //  })

      return [...dbIdsInside, ...dbIdsIntersect]
    }

    return dbIdsInside
  }
}
```